# build failed exception with wrong “com/sun/istack/FinalArrayList”

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, environment

I'm new in flutter and I created a new flutter project (default code with out change any codes) in android studio but I cant build it properly

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
com/sun/istack/FinalArrayList
> com.sun.istack.FinalArrayList

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 40s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I had tried a lot of ways but it still can't be solved  
including add the .jar into the project but its cant work

[error report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh95x.png)

Comment: what I show is what IDE show me :( I have no idea which code have problem
and the code are default new project create by android studio, I didn't change any code about it

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and I puzzled over it for an hour.

I believe my problem was that I’d incorrectly configured my build to include an unnecessary and incompatible version of Gradle’s API in the Gradle process. My `buildSrc/build.gradle` included this block:

```
dependencies {
  implementation(gradleApi())
  implementation(gradleKotlinDsl())
  ...
}
```

**Removing** the bad Gradle dependencies fixed the problem.